# Player doesn't move on ground but does when above it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am unable to move player on ground. But if I try to move it in air, it does move. I don't know what's wrong. Here's the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class playerJump : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) && rb.transform.position.y==1)
        {
            rb.AddForce(0, 7, 0, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            rb.AddForce(4*Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) )
        {
            rb.AddForce(-4 * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow) )
        {
            rb.AddForce(0, -7, 0, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }

    }

}
```

No error messages.

Comment: What is the friction of the physics materials of the player and ground? Maybe simply the force you apply is not enough to overcome the static friction.